# How get the raw file or raw directory in android?

Tags: android, file, resourcedictionary

I want try to [oobjloader](https://github.com/seanrowens/oObjLoader). (free wave 3d format loader) I loaded the first .obj but didn't find the raw dir. (or just didn't find the file)

```
            Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.cube1);
            String filename = url.toString();

            try {
                Build builder = new Build();
                Parse obj = new Parse(builder, filename);
            } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("trace FileNotFoundException loading file " + filename + ", e=" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                System.out.println("trace IOException loading file " + filename + ", e=" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How get to raw file dir url?

Error:

```
    10-18 22:10:42.714    6136-6136/com.solar.asc.solar I/System.out﹕ trace FileNotFoundException loading file android.resource://com.solar.asc.solar/2131099648, e=java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.resource:/com.solar.asc.solar/2131099648: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    10-18 22:10:42.714    6136-6136/com.solar.asc.solar W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.resource:/com.solar.asc.solar/2131099648: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    10-18 22:10:42.714    6136-6136/com.solar.asc.solar W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
    10-18 22:10:42.714    6136-6136/com.solar.asc.solar W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
```

I have also tried other formats but didn't help.

```
"android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/cube1"
"android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/cube1.obj"
```

Thx all answare.

Answer (score 0):

```
If wanna use the cube1.obj file from raw, you can do it this way

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File outFile = null;
        try 
        {
            in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cube1);
            outFile = new File(<path where you are going to store this raw file>, <what will be name of file> );
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BBConstants.KILO_VALUE];
            int read;
            while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(IOException e) 
    {

    }
```

now outFile will contains your cube1.obj data and you can use it where you want to use.

Comment: Thx, the answer, but I don't want the .obj content. I want resource raw file url or raw dir url. I will give the file url the external library. (oobjloader) Just not found the file.

Comment: I guess you get uri as file:///android_res/raw/<file name> can you try this.